# C# SqlCommands are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a problem that the code isn't working, I'm trying to populate the database that saved in localhost on SQL Server but the code is doing nothing :(

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 0 && listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string id = "select studentID from student where studentName like '%" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "%'";

            SqlCommand a = new SqlCommand(id, conn);

            a.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader reader = a.ExecuteReader();

            string s = reader.GetString(0);

            string q = "insert into Borrow values (" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()
                + ", " + s + " , '" + DateTime.Now + "' , Null)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, conn);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Book is now Borrowed");

            string tmp = "update Book set quantity=quantity-1 where bookID " + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            SqlCommand tm = new SqlCommand(tmp, conn);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: No purpose to the first `a.ExecuteNonQuery();` Need a `reader.Read();` You don't need a new the command every time.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Define "not working"

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple problems with this code, unfortunately none of the <strike>existing</strike> (now deleted) answers even mention, let alone help to fix.

- There's the SQL Injection risk marc_s warned about.
- All these commands must be inside a transaction.
- You are using `like` to get the student id, but you get the name from a list box - so why not have the id already as the value of the ListBoxItem?
- Before you can borrow a book, you must first make sure you have at least one copy left to borrow
- You are swallowing exceptions
- You are using a class-level variable for `SqlConnection`, while `SqlConnection` is best used as a local variable inside a using statement.
- You are mixing code with display - this will be impossible or at least very hard to test. Testability is a part of Maintainability.
- Your variable naming is terrible. A variable name should be meaningful - so that when someone reads the code they can get the meaning of the variable just by reading it's name.
- The only thing that should be inside the `try` block is the actual database access. Exceptions and `Try...catch` blocks are for things you can't test or control in your code.

All of that being said, here is a **somewhat** improved version of your code **as a starting point**. Please try to improve it further to fix all (or at least most of) the issues I've listed above:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 0 && listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {            
        using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var trn = con.BeginTransaction();
            var sqlGetStudentId = "select studentID from student where studentName = @studentName";   
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlGetStudentId, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string studentId = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();

                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(studentId))
                    {
                        // Note: You must first check if there are books left to borrow!
                        cmd.CommandText = "update Book set quantity=quantity-1 where bookID = @BookId";
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Borrow (/* Alwasy specify columns list! */) values (@IAmGuessingBookId, @StudentId, GETDATE(), NULL)";
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IAmGuessingBookId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentId;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        trn.Commit();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // Do something with the exception!
                    // show an error description to the client,
                    // log for future analisys
                    trn.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```