# Delay in a task

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, delay

Cannot get a Delay in a task.
The Sync does not delay at all.
The Async stops at `await Task.Delay(delay);`.

I tried:

```
Task wait4me = Task.Delay(1000);
await wait4me;
```

and it did not work - it stops at `await wait4me;`.

```
Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(int delay)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"TaskOfTResult_MethodSync delay = {delay}  {DateTime.Now}");
    int hours = 10; 
    Task.Delay(delay);
    Debug.WriteLine($"TaskOfTResult_MethodSync after delay  {DateTime.Now}");
    return Task.FromResult(hours);
}
async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync(int delay)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync  delay = {delay}   {DateTime.Now}");
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    Debug.WriteLine($"After await Task.Delay({delay})  {DateTime.Now}");
    int hours = 11;
    return hours;
}
```

Test

```
Task<int> task = TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(1000);
Debug.WriteLine("before task.Wait");
task.Wait();
Debug.WriteLine("after  task.Wait");
int i = task.Result;
Debug.WriteLine($"i = {i}");
Debug.WriteLine($"");


Task<int> taskA = TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync(1000);
Debug.WriteLine("before taskA.Wait");
taskA.Wait();
Debug.WriteLine("after  taskA.Wait");
i = taskA.Result;
Debug.WriteLine($"i = {i}");
Debug.WriteLine($"");
```

Comment: [it did not work is not very specific...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198640/c-sharp-sqlcommands-are-not-working/50198717#comment87414240_50198717)

Comment: Down votes what is the problem?  I provide the problem, code, and test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it as

```
Task.Delay(delay).Wait()
```

Comment: This fixed the syntax but the problem that it blocks.  'Task<int> task = TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(1000);' does not complete until the Delay completes.  The real purpose is to load some data and keep the UI responsive.