# WPF update UI from async method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, methods

In public `MainWindow()` I call `TestTask3(10000);`. A TextBlock Text is bound to Answer in the XAML. The `get` is called and the initial value is displayed.  I see the `set` call NotifyPropertyChanged.  But the `get` is not called a second time to get the new value.  I also have a button that changes Answer and that does change the TextBlock.

How to fix this or another approach?   I want to keep the UI reactive and update some UI elements after a delay.

```
private int answser = -2;
public int Answer
{
    get { return answser; }
    set
    {
        if (answser != value)
        {
            answser = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Answer");
        }
    }
}
public async void TestTask3(int delay)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"TestTask3");
    int answer = -1;
    int i = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // … do compute-bound work here  
        Task.Delay(delay);
        answer = -1;
        return answer;
    });
    Debug.WriteLine($"TestTask3   {i}");
    Answer = answer;
    //return answer;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t use the same names for local variables and class fields, it’s very confusing. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the setter and stepping through?

Comment: Yeah this is confusing, i cant see how on earth the property Answer would get updated twice anyway (if i'm understanding you correctly)

Comment: @DaveM As stated I see NotifyPropertyChanged called.  That is how is see that.

Comment: @TheGeneral It gets updated if I change Answer in a button click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Delay(delay)` is awaitable method.

Following solution works for me. I took a long loop calculation and it returns me result on UI after 10 seconds. Tested and working.

```
public async void TestTask3(int delay)
{
    int answer = -1;
    int i = await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // … do compute-bound work here  
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000000; j++)
        {
            answer += j;
        }

        await Task.Delay(delay);

        //answer = -1;
        return answer;
    });
    Answer = answer;
    //return answer;
}
```

Usage:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await TestTask3(10000);
}
```

Comment: So it was missing an async.  Not sure how that broke it but I am just glad it is fixed.

Comment: I am glad to help. Cheers :)

Comment: @paparazzo Since you should usually avoid `async void` methods (except event handlers), you may declare `public async Task<int> TestTask3(int delay)` and make it `return answer`. Then call it like `Answer = await TestTask3(10000);`

Comment: @Clemens That syntax throws a design time error for me. ` int ans = TestTask3(1000, token).Result;` is valid syntax but is hangs on that statement.

Comment: @Clemens This is how I wanted to do it as it returns a value.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281183/delay-in-a-task  Problem is even with the answer it blocks on Delay.

Comment: It must be `int ans = await TestTask3(...)`. Don't use `Result`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27464287/1136211